# MGCV: Can I extract individual fitted values form the additive functions from gam?

Tags: regression, nonparametric, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am fitted a generalized additive model (GAM). For this questions, let's say I have four components:

$E[Y | X] = \sum_{i = 1}^4 f_i(x_{ij})$

I would like to be able to see the values $\widehat{f}(x)$ for all the x in my dataset. I do not need to be able to work with the function or an approximation of it, the fitted values will be fine.

I take an example straight from the mgcv documentation:

```
set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
```

I think R must store the fitted values from each of the smooth functions s(x0), s(x1), s(x2), and s(x3) because if I plot the GAM with:

```
plot(b) #You'll be prompted to press return to see plots
```

I get four separate plots.

Is there any way for me to access these fitted values that R is using to plot the function fits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get what you want is to use `predict()` with `type = "terms"`

```
library("mgcv")
set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,dist="normal",scale=2)
b <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
pp <- predict(b, type = "terms")
```

`pp` contains evaluations of the fitted splines at the observed data

```
> head(pp)
       s(x0)      s(x1)      s(x2)       s(x3)
1 -0.2232118  0.1753416  0.7538020  0.26473299
2  0.3898187 -0.1265794 -0.5653391  0.09929927
3  0.5535082 -1.7219987 -3.6793603  0.03594382
4 -0.2864892 -1.9565823  5.4408902 -0.02271030
5 -0.3871858  3.1875066  3.1850072  0.22702914
6 -0.3857356  1.7962746 -3.0800611  0.03967740
> attr(pp, "constant")
(Intercept) 
   7.833279
```

The fitted values of the model are `rowSums(pp) + attr(pp, "constant")`, whilst the values in the columns are the contributions to the fitted values of each smooth.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!