# Extract smooths from different gams with mgcv and combine them in one plot

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I asked this question already a little confusing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110106/combine-gam-smooths-of-multiple-covariates-in-one-plot-in-r?noredirect=1#comment111857791_63110106
but I think my skills aren't sufficient to implement this answer. (and I know there is a question that is very similar here: [MGCV: Can I extract individual fitted values form the additive functions from gam?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/325494/mgcv-can-i-extract-individual-fitted-values-form-the-additive-functions-from-ga))

What I have is a list with fitted gams. Each has 5 smooths (covariates). What I'd like to do is to extract the first, second, third.... smooth from each fitted gam and plot them together in one plot. I'm doing that, because each gam was fitted with slightly different values for the convariates as I smoothed a terrain model. So I'd like to compare the smooths for the same covariates (like the height(dem), or the slope) right next to each other in one plot.

I found some useful help on how to extract the smooth-values here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480388/how-to-fit-a-smooth-curve-to-my-data-in-r

But when I'm doing:

```
# extract the fitted gam for the srtm
srtm_dem = predict(gam_models$srtm, type = "terms")
# extract the third smooth (the covariate called "dem")
srtm_dem = srtm_dem[,3]
# make it a dataframe
df = as.data.frame(cbind(srtm_dem, 1:length(srtm_dem)))
# rename second column 
names(df)[[2]] = "x"
# plot it
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=x, y=srtm_dem)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="gam", formula = srtm_dem ~ poly(x,4))
```

I get this:
[image]

While what I really want is the upper right smooth from this:

[image]

I fit the gams using this function:

```
my.gam <- function(formula, data, family = binomial, k = 5) {
  response.name <- as.character(formula)[2]
  predictor.names <- labels(terms(formula))
  # checks whether there are logical or factorial variables in the predictor variables
  categorical <- sapply(data[,predictor.names], is.logical) |
    sapply(data[,predictor.names], is.factor)

  formula <- paste(response.name, "~",
                   paste(predictor.names[categorical], "+"),
                   paste("s(", predictor.names[!categorical], ", k=", k, ")", collapse = "+"))
  formula <- as.formula(formula)
  fit <- gam(formula, data, family = family, select=TRUE)
  return(fit)
}
```

And afterwards I put them in a list called `gam_models`. Anyone might have an idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I am sure [SO] would welcome a version of this question that included a minimally reproducible, self-contained example.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right! I'll try to provide it:)